# Popup JQuery modal on dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a requirement to do some logic execution upon change of dropdownlist value. Before executing the logic i need to take user confirmation and then call server  side method to complete the process. Not sure How to call server side method based on modal popup confirmation response from user. So if user confirms with Yes button on the modal popup server side code should be called otherwise do nothing.

Here is the code i have . Server side does not get called upon modal popup confirmation.

```
function PopupDialog(title, text) {
    var div = $('<div>').html('<br>'+text).dialog({
    title: title,
    modal: true,
    height: 190,
    width: 320,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');

        },
        "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');

        }
     }
     });

     return true;
  };



 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdTransactions" SkinID="gridviewskin"  
    AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="30" Width="100%" 
    OnRowDataBound="grdTransactions_RowDataBound"
    OnDataBound="grdTransactions_DataBound"  
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdTransactions_SelectedIndexChanged">

   .............

<asp:TemplateField Visible="true" HeaderText="Status" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus"  Visible="False" Text='<%# ShowStatus( Container.DataItem ) %>' />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTransactionList" AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTransactionList_SelectedIndexChanged" onchange="return PopupDialog('Remittance Confirmation','Are you sure you want to update the status?.');"  runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <br/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**The server side code is below:**

```
protected void ddlTransactionList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
      EventArgs e)
{
    //Your Code
    if (OnDataChanged != null)
        OnDataChanged(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete code to your asp.net page? An easy solution would be to make sure that the [Yes] button is an ASP.NET object with runat="Server" value... post your asp.net code and I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated HTML code of your page and have a closer look on your dropdown. It should look like this:

```
<select name="gridView$ctl02$ddlTransactionList" onchange="return PopupDialog(&#39;Remittance Confirmation&#39;,&#39;Are you sure you want to update the status?.&#39;);setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;gridView$ctl02$ddlTransactionList\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="gridView_ddlTransactionList_0">
```

The problem is that you "return" the outcome of your PopupDialog so that the `__doPostback` function (AutoPostBack) has no chance of getting called. My advice: Only return if the user rejects the change. If the user agrees dont return anything.

Edit (forgot post the solution code)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTransactionList" AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTransactionList_SelectedIndexChanged" onchange="if(! PopupDialog('Remittance Confirmation','Are you sure you want to update the status?.')){return false;}"  runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```